# How does MobileVLCKit play a video stream with some empty frames?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How does MobileVLCKit play a video stream with some empty frames?

My code is as follows：

```
NSMutableDictionary *mediaDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[mediaDictionary setObject:@"50000" forKey:@"network-caching"];
self.vlcplayer = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] init];
// self.vlcplayer = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"-vvvv"]];
[self.vlcplayer setDelegate:self];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.videoURL];
self.vlcplayer.media = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:url];
[self.vlcplayer.media addOptions:mediaDictionary];
self.vlcplayer.drawable = _PlayView;
[self.vlcplayer play];
```

The effect of playback is that the video and audio are not synchronized; the frame rate of the video stream is 30, of which 5 frames are Blank frames; when playing a video stream without Blank frames, it can be played normally;
How do I set up to play a video stream with Blank frames? Thanks!

Comment: Can VLCMediaPlayer do frame skipping?